# (node:3236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am pretty new to node.js(and programming overall) and have run into an error while developing my express application. The full error message is

> (node:12896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at _callee$ (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\src\routes/admin.js:39:24)
>       at tryCatch (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:22)
>       at Generator.prototype. [as next] (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:97:21)
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\src\routes\admin.js:11:103)
>       at _next (C:\Viktor Filer\Matkort1.1\src\routes\admin.js:13:194)
>   (node:12896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:12896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

And my code looks like this.

```js
router.post("/addRestaurant", async(req, res) => {
    if (req.body.password && req.body.username && req.body.name) {
        if (await models.RestaurantAccount.findOne({
                username: req.body.username
            }) || await models.Restaurant.findOne({
                name: req.body.name
            })) {
            return res.send("Information sent is already in use");
        } else {
            let restaurant = models.Restaurant({
                name: req.body.name,
            })
            restaurant.save();

            let password = await argon2.hash(req.body.password);

            let restaurantAcc = models.RestaurantAccount({
                username: req.body.username,
                password: password,
                restaurant: restaurant._id,
            })

            restaurantAcc.save();

            return res.send("Restaurant added succesfully");
        }
    } else {
        return res.send("Insuficient information")
    }
})
```

This is not all the code of the application but I am pretty confident the error resides somewhere in
this piece of code. I have tried doing some research on this issue but not found anything that fully helps me understand how to solve this error.

If I remove the await keyword before the has function I use(argon2) this error does not show but other 
errors come since I am trying to save the password before it's finished hashing

Any suggestions on how to work this problem?

Comment: It looks like one of your async calls threw an error that was not handled. Does `models.RestaurantAccount.findOne` ever throw an exception? You should also wrap `argon2.hash` in a try-catch.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for the suggestions. Although I do not think the issue can be in models.RestaurantAccount.findOne() .
When I comment that part of the code out the same issue remains. Also, I wrapped
the argon2 in hash function and that didn't remove the error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I am just going off the error message. It mentions promise's not being handled multiple time, so, I am assuming one of your awaits is throwing an error that is not caught by anything.

Comment: Also. What version of Node are you running? and are you using babel?

Comment: @Jacob I am using v12.15.0 of node and yes I am using babel. I believe that somehow the issue lays in the argon2.hash() but I can't figure out how to work around it. I tried restructuring the code by using .then() and .catch() instead of await with the argon2.has() function but the same issue remains. 
Also, I forgot to mention earlier. The response I get is a HTML file with
the title "error" and "<pre>Cannot POST /admin/addRestaurant</pre>"

Comment: Can you show your argon2 import and also try console.logging `req.body.password` before calling `.hash` and 'password ' after the `hash` call. to narrow down if `argon2.hash()` is the issue.

Comment: import argon2 from "argon2"; (in the top of the js file)
I did log the password before and after and the both look correct. 
The reason I think the problem is in the argon2.hash is since the error remains even if I comment out all the other code and only leaves that function and the return res.send; in the code.

Comment: I decided to write a route without all the other parts that are not causing this error. `router.post("/test", async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    argon2.hash(req.body.password).then((hash) =>{
        console.log(hash)
        res.send(hash);
    })
})
`
The exact same issue remains here

Comment: Just confirming you have node-gyp globally installed and GCC >= 5 / Clang >= 3.3

Comment: I am not sure about what version of gcc I have. But can that really be the issue if
the password still is getting hashed. The console.log(hash) command is logging
a hashed password

Comment: Can you try removing the hash call and just directly assigning password to the hash that you have console.logged.

Comment: The hash that I have 'console.log(hash)' is the one from the hash argon2.hash call

Comment: Yep, so you can test it without using agron2.hash and see if it now works. If so, it is somehow your agron setup, otherwise, it will be some other part of your code.

Comment: In the code there is only two functions(if I do not count the console.log()) used, 'argon2.hash()' and 'res.send() ' . 
If I remove the 'argon2.hash()' there would be only 'res.send()' and that would not throw any error

Comment: Isn't there still `models.RestaurantAccount.findOne`, `restaurant.save` , `models.RestaurantAccount` and `restaurantAcc.save()`? Could you posible add the code that you tried after removing `argon2.hash`?

Comment: I built a new route with only argon2.hash() and res.send() to more easily identify the problem. So I know that for some reason that part of the code is not working. My theory is that argon for some reason sents a response. Here is the route have made to more easily understand the program. `router.post("/test", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    await argon2.hash(req.body.password).then((hash) =>{
        console.log(hash)
        res.send(hash);
    })
  
})`

Comment: @Jacob I realised that the problem was in a completly diffrent part of the code. Thanks a lot for your attempts in helping me with the error. This has taugth me a bit about what aproach to take in future error debugging.